# configure codeigniter website to open website on other hosting account

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, server, cpanel

Suppose there is a website www.example.com with a web hosting account (Shared Hosting - Linux Server).

There is another website www.example2.com with a web hosting account (Shared Hosting - Linux Server) and having a sub-folder named example

I want to make configuration in such a way that when user opens http://www.example.com or http://example.com or https://www.example.com or https://example.com, the website lying under www.example2.com/example should get open but in the url bar, it should show example.com and its subpath. Visitor should get a feel that he is still on example.com, he should not know that the files of example.com are lying in example2.com/example

Codeigniter is mentioned here because the website present in example2.com/example is built using Codeigniter.

I have gone through various questions regarding URL masking on this forum and found the following solutions:

1. Using Iframe, but seems like it is not a perfect approach as it might hurt responsiveness and SEO, if not done with expertise.
2. Using Add on Domain, but add on domain facility is not available on my server, I can just create Domain Aliases
3. ProxyPass: I am not sure about it, never heard of it before and couldnot find a detailed implementation guidance.
4. mod_proxy with mod_redirect: Again, I am not sure about it, never heard of it before and couldnot find a detailed implementation guidance.
5. Someone said: *You must then configure your home server to accept requests for this subdomain. (Probably through a ServerName or ServerAlias directive in a  on your home (web) server.)* Can this be done on my shared hosting
   server where I have limited access?

**UPDATE**
I have tried the following:

```
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "http://example2.com/example/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example2.com/example/"
```

I got the following:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

Where I am wrong.

Comment: Presumably `example.com` and `example2.com` are pointing to two entirely different (shared) servers?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, they are going to be on separate servers.